# tensorboard doesn't show any graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to see tensorboard graph.
I used a example code in tensorflow tutorial([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros))

And I modified a little bit code.

```
....
....
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/home/(my_directory)",sess.graph)
for i in range(2000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1],keep_prob: 1.0})
print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  else :
    summary =  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1],keep_prob: 0.5})
    writer.add_summary(summary,i)
print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

And in terminal, I typed "tensorboard --logdir="/home/(my_directoory)"

then, in chrome browser, enter the tensorboard through port number 6006.

But, there is no graph as below... what should I do to see my graph?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lCjt.png)

Comment: The image shows you are under "SCALARS" tab. Did you click the "GRAPHS" tab?